# MongoDB does not reclaim space despite running repairDatabase()

Tags: mongodb

We have been running mongoDB in single unsharded instance, just one database. The size of data files was 0.45 GB. When I looked into the storageSize of all the collections, the total size was ~85 MB. In a bid to reclaim unused space, we ran repairDatabase(), with understanding that file sizes grow from 64 to 128 to 256 and so on till 2 GB. Since the mongo object data we have (85 MB) can be accommodated in 64 + 128 MB files, we were expecting the 256 MB file to be reclaimed. However, to our surprise, no space was reclaimed.

Can someone let us know the logic based on which we can find how much space would be reclaimed? Essentially, given total disk space a database takes, and given total mongo object data size, can one estimate accurately how much space would be reclaimed?

The following is the db.stats() output as requested in a comment:

```
> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "analytics_data_1",
        "collections" : 12,
        "objects" : 207223,
        "avgObjSize" : 353.6659347659285,
        "dataSize" : 73287716,
        "storageSize" : 84250624,
        "numExtents" : 43,
        "indexes" : 26,
        "indexSize" : 21560112,
        "fileSize" : 469762048,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
>
```

Comment: no space would be reclaimed if you don't have any fragmentation (due to deletes, document moves, etc).   Why don't you provide output to db.stats() and individual collection stats?  What makes you think there is any reclaimable space?  Don't forget about space for indexes.

Comment: I've added storageSize of every collection and index. That equals 85 MB.

Comment: You do know about preallocation right? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database the first two files have data in them, the third one is preallocated so that when you fill your 128MB file the DB doesn't have to pause while waiting for the next file to be allocated.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, let me know if the following is correct:

If the total data size is 64+128+256+512+ 20
If the total file size is 64+128+256+512+1024+2048

In such case, no file would be reclaimed, as one extra chunk is preallocated. However, if

If the total data size is 64+128+256+512+ 20
If the total file size is 64+128+256+512+1024+2048+2048

in such case, the last 2048 MB file would be reclaimed.

Let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: the last (largest) file is always empty.  I'm not sure I can parse your equations but if your data requires two data files then you will see three in the directory (in addition to the .ns file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [storage FAQ explains](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database) that an extra file is always pre-allocated and as soon as you start writing to it, `mongod` will preallocate the next file.

Repair won't reclaim any space that would normally exist - it can only help if you've deleted a lot of data or dropped some collections.

Disabling preallocation can save you space but will cost you in performance as the file will be allocated when it's actually needed to write to - and that will slow down inserts.

Comment: Can you please share some links as to how noprealloc and smallfiles have caused problems in production? We are toying with idea to use them in production, but want to be sure before we go ahead.

Comment: noprealloc means if you are writing 5MB of data and run out of room in the current file after 4MB the write will have to block and wait while the next file is allocated.  With prealloc it would have been allocated in the background as soon as you started writing into the last empty file.   So in production this can manifest as occasional but seemingly random long pause when the system is non-responsive.

Comment: smallfiles can simply cause more fragmentation as larger collections and indexes may be scattered across multiple files (which may be located on different parts of the disk)

Comment: (Regarding smallfiles) But wouldn't that be corrected if we ran repairDatabase() periodically?